# Sending a file via POST using raw HTTP (PuTTY)

Tags: http, post, putty

If I set up an HTML page with the following form:

```
<html>

    <body>
        <form action="upload_file.php"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

I can upload a file to upload_file.php where I can handle it using a PHP script.

For testing purposes, I need to do the same using raw HTTP via a [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) session.

I can do a normal POST (just sending text data) this way:

```
POST /test_post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11

name=myname
```

How can I send a file this way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use `multipart` content-type and encode the file data into hex/binary

Try the following in telnet:

```
POST /the_url HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: xxxx
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------31063722920652
------------------------------31063722920652
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"

value_for_a
------------------------------31063722920652
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="b"

value_for_b
------------------------------31063722920652
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="c"; filename="myfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

            This is a test 
            and more

-----------------------------31063722920652
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Submit
-----------------------------31063722920652--
```

Remember that an extra newline is necessary between field name and its data. Also, update the `Content-Length` value.

Comment: How would I accomodate the file in the new content length? Will it be the size of the file in bytes?

Comment: I have completed the raw data in my answer. It now contains a text file payload. Content-Length will be the complete size of payload (including the file) in bytes

Comment: Content-Length is the size in bytes of data that is sent starting from the first `boundary` till the last one.

Comment: Can you please tell me what does the number 31063722920652 represent in the request?

Comment: @HemalChevli it is an arbitrary value, you can set it to anything at all. I think the limit is 70 bytes. This delimiter value should not show up in the request data, otherwise it will be treated as a boundary.

Answer (score 5):

Open a port with netcat and save the incoming request:

```
nc -l -p 1090 > income-http.txt
```

Then modify your form to send the data to the netcat:

```
<form action="http://localhost:1090/upload_file.php" 
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Submit the form from your browser. You can find the full raw request with the contents of the file in the `income-http.txt` file.

Saving the `income-http.txt` is an one-time activity. Later you can send the saved request out any times. Please note that you should edit the `Host:` header in the saved txt.

Comment: I really like the idea of being able to analyze the incoming request. But unfortunately, opening a port isn't an option for me. Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: You have to do it just on your local machine and only once. After you get the income-http.txt you could send it any times.

Comment: Oh, you mean I open the port on the local machine and don't have to forward it at the router? I don't have access to the router. I'll give netcat a shot.

Comment: btw, is it possible to install netcat on my linux web hsoting server?

Comment: Yes, just on local machine, you don't have to route it to anywhere. It just saves the incoming request to the txt file and after the saving you won'tt need it anymore. Netcat install: `aptitude install netcat` on Debian. Other distributions usually also have netcat package.