# Sending a file via POST PuTTY

Tags: http, protocols, putty

I have found the following already:
[Sending a file via POST using raw HTTP (Putty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553005/sending-a-file-via-post-using-raw-http-putty)

However, when I send my request, Putty screws up the damn empty line. No matter what I do 
putty is always making an `ENTER` out of my *empty line* so it sends the request before I'm finished typing:

```
POST /somepath/ http/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Lenght:15

hhhteaj=555555
```

The problem is that my post request MUST be with that empty line or it's not the correct syntax. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the fact that you misspelled:

```
Content-Lenght:15
```

Causing a problem? Should be:

```
Content-Length:15
```

Comment: SErIouSlY a typo did it!

However everything lead me to the conclusion that something is not working with the input field. When i did send the request without the parameter it did not give me an error or something the server just asked for the parameter. 

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @JonasShinaniganz, sorry I didn't see this comment before I asked if you accepted the right answer. Surprised me too (I thought is was worth mentioning but assumed there was also some other problem). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this problem. If you paste the request from the clipboard into the PuTTY session (right mouse click does this in my configuration), then press enter, the entire request gets sent. You can use any text editor (Notepad, Vim, emacs, Kedit, etc.) to create the request and copy it to the clip board.

If this is inconvenient, it seems you can copy just a newline to the clipboard and use the right mouse button to past a blank line that will not cause the session to end.