# Where can I see a list of all necessary headers for HTTP requests

Tags: http, post, get

Where can I see a list of all necessary headers for HTTP requests (for example, GET and POST)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use HTTP/1.1 GET, it is only **required** to specify the `Host:` option, like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

If you use HTTP/1.0, you don't even need the `Host:`.

If you want to use a POST-query with form-data, you may look at this answer: [Sending a file via POST using raw HTTP (Putty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553005/sending-a-file-via-post-using-raw-http-putty)

Here is the specification for all HTTP/1.1-header fields:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html . You can tak a look at the `Host:` option in point 14.23 in this specification.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
>   messages

and that's the only required field ever.

Comment: I don't see any list of neccessary headers on this page, only the list of all available headers