# ff HttpRequester addon - upload files with post data

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

anyone know how to send file in this addon?
I know hot to send post data, but not with files

Comment: yes many ways and many topics in firefox-addon section about this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[firefox-addon]+upload if you something more specific after reading those topics be sure to update this question and we'll help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this (find in [Sending a file via POST using raw HTTP (Putty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553005/sending-a-file-via-post-using-raw-http-putty)):

```
nc -l -p 1090 > income-http.txt
```

and in code:

```
<form action="http://localhost:1090/upload_file.php" 
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

after this add content type with `multipart/form-data; boundary=XXX` and choose load content from this file

Comment: This has nothing to do with firefox.